# Using only pure javascript how to get file name, format and content of a browsed file

Tags: javascript

I need to get the name, format and content of a browsed file only, multiple files not required. Even I cant use any HTML5 API/jQuery. Could you please guide me, using only pure JavaScript how do I solve this.

Here is the fiddle:
[https://jsfiddle.net/summtz8m/][1]

After getting all I need to click ImportASN1 button to POST data in REST service.

Here is my HTML

```
<button class="ebBtn" id="importButt" name="importButt"><span>Import ASN1</span></button><input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile"><p id="contents"></p>
```

Here is my JS

```
    var file = document.getElemtById("myfile").files[0];
    console.log(file);
  if (file) {
    // create reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsText(file);
     reader.onload = function(e) {
       // browser completed reading file - display it
       console.log(e.target.result);
     };
   }
```

Comment: What you want is impossible. JS has no built-in mechanisms to do **anything** with files. The API you are using in your example code is an HTML 5 API.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you cannot use any HTML5 API, but you use `getElementById`, `FileReader`, and `onload`, all of which are HTML5 APIs.

Comment: Yes guys, you are correct. I am trying to find out the solution in JS instead of HTML5 API as using above HTML5 API I am getting this error "Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'." Even console.log(file) gives "undefined."

Comment: Guys!! If you have any solution to fix the error "Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader':parameter 1 is not type pf 'Blob' " please share with me.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code runs on page load. But at that time the file input is not filled out yet! Instead, listen to the `click` event on the button, or the `change` event on the file input.

In addition, there is a typo: `document.getElemtById` should be `document.getElementById`. Use the developer console in your browser (<kbd>F12</kbd> → *Console* in many browsers) to find these errors.

The file name will then be present in the [`file.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name).

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myfile").addEventListener('change', function(ev) {
    var file = ev.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        console.log(file.name, e.target.result);
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: The question said "I cant use any HTML5 API"

Comment: Yes, but @Soma seems to have confused HTML5 with an extra library, like jquery. They are using `FileReader`, which comes from the [File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/), just like `file.name`.

Comment: @Phihag, Using your code, presently I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null"

Comment: @Soma that means you have set the value of `file_input` to null somewhere else in the code. I've updated the code with a version that does not use that variable.

Comment: @Phihag, Presently I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined" .

Comment: @Soma Then you have edited the code somehow. [Here is a demo](https://phihag.de/2018/so/files.html) showing it works. Can you provide the link to a public example of yours that fails?

Comment: @Phihag, you can consider this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9dfpn7/ , I am working here in such a framework that is not available in market, though I am requesting you if this you could be able to help me on this.

Comment: Hi Phihag, would like to update you that just now I have resolved the issue. Could you please guide me to POST the data in REST Service when click on "ImportASN1" button.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fiddle fails at other parts - for instance, right in the first line, `define` is not defined. Plus, there is a lot of commented-out code and other baggage like incorrect indentation. See [the stackoverflow FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to create a good fiddle.

Comment: *How to POST file data* sounds like a new, unrelated question. [Please ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To make the code run once the button is clicked, add a `click` event handler to the button.